# python: count the number of repeating of certain variable in the df header

Tags: python-3.x

Would like to count the number of repeating of csv header

File.csv
id ab_1 ab_2 ab_3 ab_4 ac_1 ac_2 ac_3 ae_1 ae_2
1 1 1 1 0 1 3 5 2 6

Expect result: ab_ = 4 but get 0

I tried to use * to represent variable such as ab_*, but can't work, any hints?

```
_load = pd.read_csv(file.csv)
_firCol = list(_load.head(0)).count('ab_*')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than trying to use the wildcard match at the end, you can just match to the first three characters in the column string.

Also, I think you should use `df.columns` instead.

```py
_firCol = list(item[:3] for item in _load.columns).count('ab_')
```

Comment: that 'ab_' falls among the header, the number of repeats is needed for another process, and the number of headers is varying.